# What lens for Nikon night landscape / sky photography?

Tags: lens, nikon, night-photography

I wanted to take night sky / aurora photos. I have currently been using Nikon D5300 with 18-105mm f3.5-5.6 lens. However I have noticed that it needs either a bit too long to take photos at night or if I increase ISO to acceptable time, photos are too distorted. Also I would love to be able to capture more of the night sky, to have wider image.

I was thinking about purchasing another lens for night sky photography and other landscapes. I have done some research and there are often often mentioned lenses 18-35/1.8. I like f1.8 but this focal length is no better. Will changing just aperture size have impact that I am looking for? Or do I need both or prioritize focal length?
Lenses like 14/1.8 cost a few times more than my current camera + lens. I'm not sure if lenses which upgrade just one parameter will result in a noticeable change.

Also I have a phone Samsung S22 Ultra. In it, there are 2 cameras: 23mm f1.8 and 13mm f2.2. Am I better to just use that to take pictures of night sky?

Comment: Your final paragraph needs to be a separate question.

Comment: Also related: [Can I take clear night sky photographs with my smartphone?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/94814/15871) and [Milky Way with a cell phone, how is this possible?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/112389/15871)